# cURL error 28: Failed to connect to systemb port 80: Timed out for http://systemb/api/push_products

Tags: laravel, http

i have 2 web systems,system A and system B, whereby on uploading data on system A products table database,the data is saved on products table of system B simultaneously.both of the systems are in laravel 5.8.i am using an api to send data to system b.the data is being saved system A database but the data isnt sent to system B database.i havent understood where i have gone wrong with my gone code here.
here is the function that saves the data and also links the api to system B

```
    $product=new Product;
    $product->name=$request['name'];
    $product->description=$request['description'];
    $product->save();

    //data to push data to system B
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $url="http://systemb/api/push_products";
         $body = array(
           'name' => $data['name'], 
           'description' => $data['description']);
         $response = $client->post($url,$body);
```

Comment: Try to change `$data` to `$request`

Comment: @wahyu kristianto still the error appears

Comment: @WahyuKristianto thanks alot you saved me